# Raspberry Pi arkOS terminal Password not known

Tags: operating-systems, password

i anstlled arkOS on my pi, but i dont know its ip.
the adress `http://arkos:8000` does not work.
how can i log into the raspberry terminal and find out the ip adress?

Answer (score 1):

you may connect TV and keyboard and log in directly (not over the network), then type `ifconfig` to find out your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your router to see the ip of arkos. For example, it is 192.168.2.11 in my local network.

[image: ip of arkos]

To see your router, try going to 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, etc. in your browser.

Comment: Also, try `http://arkos.local:8000` instead